# Print only once in a live detection model

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, machine-learning, object-detection

```
import cv2
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
import os
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_json

root_dir = os.getcwd()
# Load Face Detection Model
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("models/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
# Load Anti-Spoofing Model graph
json_file = open('antispoofing_models/finalyearproject_antispoofing_model_mobilenet.json','r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
# load antispoofing model weights 
model.load_weights('antispoofing_models/finalyearproject_antispoofing_model_99-0.976842.h5')
print("Model loaded from disk")
# video.open("http://192.168.1.101:8080/video")
# vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
# time.sleep(2.0)

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    try:
        ret,frame = video.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:  
            face = frame[y-5:y+h+5,x-5:x+w+5]
            resized_face = cv2.resize(face,(160,160))
            resized_face = resized_face.astype("float") / 255.0
            # resized_face = img_to_array(resized_face)
            resized_face = np.expand_dims(resized_face, axis=0)
            # pass the face ROI through the trained liveness detector
            # model to determine if the face is "real" or "fake"
            preds = model.predict(resized_face)[0]
            # print(preds)
            if preds> 0.45:
                label = 'spoof'
                cv2.putText(frame, label, (x,y - 10),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0,0,255), 2)
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w,y+h),
                    (0, 0, 255), 2)
                print("SPOOFED FACE DETECTED")
                break
            else:
                label = 'real'
                cv2.putText(frame, label, (x,y - 10),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0,255,0), 2)
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w,y+h),
                (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            break
    except Exception as e:
        pass
video.release()        
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The above code detects the real and spoofed faces but I want to  `print("SPOOFED FACE DETECTED")` only once in 1 min when the `preds> 0.45` but it prints it continuously.
how to add a time delay that after every 1 min on detecting *spoofed face*, it should  `print("SPOOFED FACE DETECTED")` but the program will keep on executing.

Answer (score 0):

It will print if `preds> 0.45` while the while loop is running. If you want to print once every one minute without interrupting the while loop then you'll need to use a timer and adjust your condition.

I'm not familiar with the openCV library, so I'm not sure if there's a better way to track the elapsed time of the capture. But, using the included python time library, you could do something like

```py
while True:
    start = time.time() # CHANGE start time counter
    delta = 60
    try:
        ret,frame = video.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:  
            face = frame[y-5:y+h+5,x-5:x+w+5]
            resized_face = cv2.resize(face,(160,160))
            resized_face = resized_face.astype("float") / 255.0
            # resized_face = img_to_array(resized_face)
            resized_face = np.expand_dims(resized_face, axis=0)
            # pass the face ROI through the trained liveness detector
            # model to determine if the face is "real" or "fake"
            preds = model.predict(resized_face)[0]
            # print(preds)
            if preds> 0.45: # CHANGE; compute delta and compare with threshold
                label = 'spoof'
                cv2.putText(frame, label, (x,y - 10),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0,0,255), 2)
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w,y+h),
                    (0, 0, 255), 2)
                if (time.time() - start) >= delta:
                    print("SPOOFED FACE DETECTED")
                    start = time.time()
                break
            else:
                label = 'real'
                cv2.putText(frame, label, (x,y - 10),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0,255,0), 2)
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w,y+h),
                (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            break
    except Exception as e:
        pass
video.release()        
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I've omitted the bits outside the loop , and marked the changes for readibility

Comment: how do I compute the delta, I think if i add your code it will detect the spooked face as a real face.

Comment: the delta is computed by `time.time() - start` is just the difference between the current time and the start time. Does spoofed face mean that `preds > 0.45`?

Comment: Yes if the `preds > 0.45`, it detects the spoofed face and it still prints _SPOOFED FACE DETECTED_ continuously even after adding your code.

Comment: I've edited the answer, start should be inside the for loop. should work now

Comment: nope this will not work I think I have to set a delay for 60 seconds after detecting a spooked face

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't work? Are you still seeing continuous prints? If you call sleep you will halt all code execution. Again, I don't know what you are doing in the loop, but whatever it is will only happen once every 60 seconds if you do that. My answer assumes that you only want to enter the `if preds > 0.45` branch every 60 seconds and to the rest of the computations all the time. If that's not what you want, edit your question to explain the code and what you want to do a bit more and I see if I can help further

Comment: After adding your code it detects the spooked face as a real face. as I said earlier. and no I want to execute the code all the time but just  `print("SPOOFED FACE DETECTED")` after 60 seconds

Comment: `time.time() - start` is always less than 0.1 that's why it never enters the `if preds > 0.45` statement and prints everything as real

Comment: you're right, the logic is wrong' cause you always break from the loop, so the timer is reset. You need to reset the timer, every 60 seconds then and put the print statement there. Let me have another go